# Wrong COS value in Flutter dart

Tags: flutter

My code in flutter is...

```dart
var a01=Angle.gradians(108).cos;
print(a01);
a01= -0.12533323356430437
```

First, I imported the Angle package in flutter and used it to take cos of any value,
the calculator is giving the value of 180 cos is `-0.30901699437494`, and the flutter giving the wrong value of cos... plz help.
using android studio.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be caused by different things. Your code seems off: Your code says 108 and your text says 180, that might be one reason. More likely though, you take the `Angle.gradians`, whereas what I think you might be trying is `Angle.degrees` or `Angle.turns` (there are 400 gradians in a turn, versus 2*PI radians, versus 360 degrees).

```dart
var angle = Angle.fromDegrees(108.0).cos;
print(angle); // prints -0.30901699437494734
```

Comment: Sorry bro '180' is my fault, but thanks to you for your quick answer.

Comment: Thanks to you bro, my problem has been solved.

Comment: Good to hear. If you want you can mark my answer as the solution, so other people don't look at the question thinking it isn't answered yet :P

Comment: No bro, I don't need that.